# Regular expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I have below string:

```
String line = put retur#ERns between #errf #fgrf#re paragraphs #fg^%tg2#785Ty*;
```

How can I get below values with regex:

```
#ERns
#errf
#fgrf
#re
#fg^%tg2
#785Ty*
```

My code:

```
String pattern = "^#\S+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
   Log.i("log", m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex instead:

```
#[^#\s]*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HqJjwA/1)

Negated character class `[^#\s]` matches a character that is not `#` and not a whitespace.

In Java use:

```
final String pattern = "#[^#\\s]*";
```